# Programming Principles and Practice 2nd ed chapter 8 drill 1

Tags: c++, clang++

**Problem:**

I cannot get the code provided by the author to link via clang++ in chapter 8 of Programming Principles and Practice by Bjarne Stroustrup.

**Code:**

```
 ~/scratch/cpp/chp8 (09/10/2017-13:51:43[EDT]) cat my.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "my.h"
void print_foo() { std::cout << foo << std::endl; }
void print(int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }

 ~/scratch/cpp/chp8 (09/10/2017-13:52:29[EDT]) cat my.h
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);
#endif

 ~/scratch/cpp/chp8 (09/10/2017-13:52:33[EDT]) cat use.cpp
#include "my.h"

int main() {
  foo = 7;
  print_foo();
  print(99);
  return 0;
}
```

**Attempts:**

I have tried a few different ways of compiling this:

***One*** - Compile the driver app that contains the main function.

```
 ~/scratch/cpp/chp8 (09/10/2017-13:52:39[EDT]) clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++  use.cpp -o use.cpp.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "print(int)", referenced from:
      _main in use-2864c4.o
  "print_foo()", referenced from:
      _main in use-2864c4.o
  "_foo", referenced from:
      _main in use-2864c4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

***Two*** - Specifically compile just the my.cpp file and not link. Although I was successful in compiling I'm not sure how to link use.cpp with this object file now.

```
 ~/scratch/cpp/chp8 (09/10/2017-14:09:40[EDT]) clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -c my.cpp -o my.cpp.o
```

***Three*** - Use all .cpp files.

```
 ~/scratch/cpp/chp8 (09/10/2017-14:15:32[EDT]) clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ my.cpp use.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_foo", referenced from:
      print_foo() in my-2243d1.o
      _main in use-796f91.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z9print_foov)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Question:**

Besides the obvious question of what am I doing wrong, I'm more interested in what am I missing or miss understanding here?

**Note:**

I'm not looking for personal opinions or preferences on what I should or should not be doing. This is a purely education adventure that I'm taking with this book and I would like to keep it as such.

**Misc:**

```
 ~/scratch/cpp/chp8 (09/10/2017-14:15:25[EDT]) uname -a
Darwin abes-MacBook-Pro.local 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
 ~/scratch/cpp/chp8 (09/10/2017-14:15:28[EDT]) clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: You need to list all .cpp files in the command line.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for replying I tried that one as well and the linking phase failed just the same.

Comment: Note that typically, a source file `my.cpp` is compiled to an object file `my.o` not `my.cpp.o`.

Comment: You're missing the declaration of the `foo` global variable.  (Something like `int foo;`, possibly in main.cpp before the definition of `main()`.)

Comment: Note that it is sufficient to accept and upvote the correct answer. You do not need to edit your original question. In fact, doing so will likely cause confusion for future visitors who read this page.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I just wanted to make sure I gave credit to all parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get has nothing to do with the difference between compiling and linking. Rather there is an error in your code. The reason for the error is because you are **declaring** the global variable `foo` but you never **define** it. You need to add the line

```
int foo = 0;
```

to one of your .cpp files. This probably makes the most sense in `my.cpp`.

Note that using global variables like this is considered a Coding Horror. You should not do this in real code.

**Regarding compiling and linking:**

Creating an executable from your C++ takes several steps. Here we will talk about compiling versus linking and how to do each of these steps manually. There are also other steps, but I will not get into them here.

First of all, you can compile and link all of your source files all at once:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ my.cpp use.cpp
```

I'm confused why this is not working in your "Attempt three". I will look into this more shortly.

To compile and link your source code manually, you can do the following:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -c my.cpp -o my.o
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -c use.cpp -o use.o
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ my.o use.o -o use
```

Note that I compile `my.cpp` to `my.o` rather than `my.cpp.o`. This is the common convention for this.

Also, once you are comfortable with these concepts, I strongly suggest that you use a build tool such as `make` or an XCode project which manages these steps for you automatically.

Comment: That is what attempt two is, I'm just not sure how to link the object file produced and if I also have to compile my.cpp separately.

Comment: @Abraham See my edit for solving the error message in step 1.

Comment: @Abraham I will edit with a more detailed explanation shortly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentie please review the section of Attempts specifically Two. I tried that approach however the point I tried to convey with this was that I did not know what was the subsequent step/s.

Comment: @Abraham Attempt 2 successfully compiles `my.cpp` to an object file. My last sentence is referring to how to get Attempt 1 to compile without an error. You then will also need to link the two resulting .o files with another clang++ command. I am trying to work out the details for you in an edited answer.

Comment: this is correct that the compilation process worked, and I will gladly & patiently await your follow up edit.

Comment: @Abraham See my newest edit that shows how to link after you have successfully compiled each file individually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154078/discussion-between-abraham-and-code-apprentice).